# What is the different between these two rows in the JSON array which means one isn't being recognised?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an API call that retrieves an array from my database featuring `countries`, `divisions`, `teams`.

This output shows the format of the JSON when received in Swift (`teams` not shown in example:

> Optional(["countries": <__NSArrayI 0x6180001f6500>(
>       {
>       id = 1;
>       name = Denmark;
>       },
>       {
>       id = 2;
>       name = Belgium;
>       }
>       )
>       , "divisions": <__NSArrayI 0x7fc8a34455a0>(
>       {
>       Name = "ALKA SUPERLIGA";
>       "country_id" = 1;
>       id = 1;
>       },
>       {
>       Name = "PRO LEAGUE";
>       "country_id" = 2;
>       id = 2;
>       }

I am using the following function in swift to sort the `countries` and `divisions` into different string arrays to then use in an UITableView.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTeams.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                        print (json)

                        if let arr = json?["countries"] as? [[String:String]] {
                            self.countryId = arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!}
                            self.countries = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!}
                            self.teamsTableView.reloadData()
                            print ("Countries: ",self.countries)
                        }

                    if let arr = json?["divisions"] as? [[String:String]] {

                        self.divisions = arr.flatMap { $0["Name"]!}
                        self.divisionId = arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!}
                        self.teamsTableView.reloadData()
                        print ("Divisions: ",self.divisions)
                    }



                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    //membersTableView.reloadData()

}
```

The `print ("Countries: ",self.countries)` outputs as expected, below:

> Countries:  [Optional("Denmark"), Optional("Belgium")

But the `print ("Divisions: ",self.divisions)` doesn't even run.  So there must be something wrong with that IF command, yet I am using the same code as what I used from the 'countries' section.

Any ideas?

I have tried replacing `[[String : String]]` with `[[String : String?]]` but this did nothing.  I have also tried `[[String : Any]]` but this brought the following error on the arr.flapMap lines:

> '(_) -> Any' to expected argument type '(Dictionary) -> SegmentOfResult'

Comment: If I use Any, as suggested.  I get the following error: Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Any' to expected argument type '(Dictionary<String, Any>) -> SegmentOfResult' on the arr.flapMap lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in Swift 3 the common unspecified type is `Any` rather than `AnyObject`

In the given JSON

- The root object is `[String:Any]`
- The value for `divisions` is `[[String:Any]]` because it contains `String` and `<null>` types.

The value `<null>` will be replaced with `n/a`

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
       print (json)

       if let arr = json["countries"] as? [[String:String]] {
          self.countryId = arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!}
          self.countries = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!}
          self.teamsTableView.reloadData()
          print ("Countries: ",self.countries)
       }

       if let arr = json["divisions"] as? [[String:Any]] {
          self.divisions = arr.flatMap { $0["Name"] as? String ?? "n/a" }
          self.divisionId = arr.flatMap { $0["id"] as? String }
          self.teamsTableView.reloadData()
          print ("Divisions: ",self.divisions)
       }
}
```

Notes:

Do **not** use multiple arrays as data source in conjunction with `flatMap`, this is pretty error-prone, use a custom struct instead.

A `POST` request is not needed, `GET` (a data task passing the url) is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks that's really useful to know.  how do I rewrite the line: URLSession.shared.dataTask{ (response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in for use with the GET?

Comment: Just replace `request` with `myUrl!` (`URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl!)...`), the compiler infers the type.

Answer (score 0):

Probably "country_id" key has integer value and because of that "if let arr = json?["divisions"] as? [[String:String]]" statement is not working.

Always try to set [[String:Any]] to any array of dictionary if you retrieving it from server.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is of type [String:Any], thus the cast fails. Use Any:

```
if let arr = json?["divisions"] as! [[String:Any]] { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in case of `divisions` some elements contain empty (`null`) names. Which means that real type is not `[[String:String]]`, but `[[String:String?]]`

Comment: I also tried it in playground and it works. Here is my code: https://gitlab.com/snippets/30307

Comment: strange, i just copied and pasted your code from your link into my code - replacing my existing code and it didn't work?? i don't get it.

Comment: Did you get any errors? Does it work if you paste my code in playground (if yes then you need to debug through your code step by step checking what is wrong)?